# How to insert to a list of dictionaries values in a specific key

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries which is like this

```
mylist = [ {'Var1': 'one', 'Var2': 'two', 'Var3': '0'}, {'Var1': 'one', 'Var2': 'two', 'Var3': '0'} ]
```

What if i want to get the index for mylist[0]['Var1'] ?? I need to get the index of it not change it manually. Im iterrating through my list with a for loop and i need to know in what index it belongs

Comment: `mylist[0]['Var3'] = 'something_new'`

Comment: thanks for the edit azro, forgot to put in in {{ code }}

Answer (score 3):

1- You should get your **first dictionary** from the list by `mylist[0]`.

2- and then nest it with accessing your desired **key** `['Var3']`.

So the command will be: `mylist[0]['Var3'] = value`

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to work with the first dictionary in 'mylist', you can access it at:

```
mylist[0]
```

So adjusting its 'Var3's value would be

```
mylist[0]['Var3'] = 'something_new'
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of the dictionary fields can be directly overwritten.

Example: If you want to change 'Var3' key's value at the first dictionary, it would be like `mylist[0]['Var3'] = 'something'`